# What are the security concerns with running ftp on a remote linux/debian server?

Tags: security, debian, ftp

I have a rackspace hosted debian instance and need to copy sensitive files up to it.  I'm thinking of setting up an ftp server but have concerns about security as i believe credentials are passed in plaintext?  Is there an ftps i can use?  Any other options to move files over the internet securely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a SSH server on this system ? If yes, you can use it to connect to your system using sftp protocol, which is basically FTP commands over SSH. And there is no need for another user database, just reuse the one you use for SSH.
As a SFTP client, I like filezilla.

If not, vsftpd (an excellent FTP server) can be configured to enable FTP over SSL. You will need a self-signed certificate and change a few parameters in vsftpd.conf (such as ssl_enable=YES).

Also, if you know you will connect to this FTP server from one IP address only, you could add an firewall rule (iptables/netfilter) to allow connections from this IP only.

Comment: this is perfect - thanks!  not sure i'll restrict to one ip.  i am using filezilla (i use it for ftp all the time) - are my credentials transmitted securely?  or do they go in plaintext?  For server type in the filezilla interface i chose "SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocol"

Comment: Throught SFTP, your credentials and all of the data of the connection are transmitted securely. If you don't mind a bit a technicalities, take a look at the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell

Answer (score 2):

if you can ssh into your machine, you can sftp in, tools like Transmit, Cyberduck,, WinSCP, Filezilla all have support for it, you just connect to port 22 like SSH, and you keep the FTP type interface you're used to.

one addition to Julien's answer, if you aren't comfortable with iptables and only allowing access from one ip using that, you can use tcpwrappers, edit your /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny

Answer (score 1):

Using ssh/scp/sftp is the best guess.

But I would consider an encrypted filesystem too.

You have at least two critical points:

- transmission and authentication
- storage on your server (you can get hacked on any other running service too...)

Encryption can be done as

Filesystem encryption:

- Loop-aes
- dm-crypt
- ...

You can find more here: http://www.debianadmin.com/filesystem-encryption-tools-for-linux.html

File based encryption

- gpg (http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-files-with-a-password.html)
- ccrypt (http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccrypt/)
- ...

Comment: can you expand a bit on your experiences with "encrypted file system" in linux?  I am intrigued...